# Mahapps Metro: Show non-modal auto-closing message dialog at the bottom of the window

Tags: c#, wpf, github-for-windows, mahapps.metro

Is it possible in Mahapps Metro to show a standard message dialog at the bottom of the `MetroWindow` just like the [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com) app does? I want to notify the user about exceptions, but without the need to close this dialog before he/she continues using the app.

Until now I use the following code to open the message dialog, but this is a blocking way and it appears at the center of the `MetroWindow`:

```
await this.ShowMessageAsync("My title", "My error message");
```

I want to create a `Github for Windows` like dialog. You can see a screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

In `Github for Windows` you can undo any operation, but this message only appears some seconds and than auto-hides.

Comment: Looks more like a banner than a dialog--something similar to the notification banners that appear at the top/bottom of some web browsers.  I'd snoop the Github for Windows client and see how they're doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't a dialog, but the [Flyout](http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html) control with the `Position` property set to `Bottom`.

Also see this discussion on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1352